# How to connect from dblink in other server?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

i need connection with my server at other, but this connection The following error appears. example code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION attBD() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$attBD$
BEGIN
    SELECT dblink_connect('myconect', 'hostaddr=***.**.**.** port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=***');

    IF ( TG_OP = 'SELECT') THEN

        SELECT * FROM DBLINK
       ('myconect', 'select*from teste_GB')
        as func2 (id Integer,
              nome varchar);
              RETURN NEW;

              ELSE IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

              SELECT dblink_exec
              ('myconect',
            'INSERT INTO teste.teste_replica(id, nome,)
            VALUES
            (new.id, new.nome)');
            RETURN NEW;

               ELSE IF ( TG_OP = 'UPDATE' ) THEN

            SELECT dblink_exec
              ('myconect',
            'UPDATE teste.teste_replica SET id=new.id , nome= new.nome, 
            WHERE id = new.id)');
            RETURN NEW;

            ELSE IF ( TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN

            SELECT dblink_exec
              ('myconect',
            'DELETE from teste.teste_replica WHERE id = old.id');
            RETURN OLD;

    END IF; END IF; END IF; END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$attBD$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

When running a code, comes the following message:
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
What do I do?

Comment: As the hint says, if you want to discard the results of a `SELECT`, use `PERFORM` instead

Comment: ok, but I changed , Even so this is still same the ERROR. What do I do?